# Как программно отправить ссылку кому-либо в телеграм?

Tags: android, kotlin, telegram, android-intent

Пишу приложение на kotlin под Android. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать отправку ссылки из Activity (предположим, по нажатию кнопки) кому-либо из списка контактов в телеграм?
Понимаю, что это делается через Intent, но не понимаю, как именно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, приблизительно так:

```
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
    type = "text/plain" //для URL можно использовать text/x-uri
}

val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
startActivity(shareIntent)
```

`Intent.createChooser()` вызывает диалог к юзеру со списком приложений поддерживающих прием вашего интента. Можно и без этого - если знаете какое приложение можно вручную указать имя пакета приложения телеграмм, но так не стоит делать.

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!